# Connecting .xlsm Excel file to C# for retrieving and updating excel file

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba

I have few excel files with Macros. All the data is in different sheets in one file. I have using OleDB connection where the connection state is always closed. I recently used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel where I get a exception from HRESULT.

I want to get the data from each file and display as a data table in the form.

This is the recently used method:

```
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:/Resources/Excel File 2.xlsm");
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets[1];

                MessageBox.Show(xlWorkSheet.get_Range("D1", "D10").Value2.ToString());

        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
```

Release Object method:

```
    private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

I got this example from stack overflow but it didn't work either. I need a good solution to connect the .xlsm file and retrieve data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) library it's useful and you don't need to use the Interop.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily import data from Excel into a DGV, using this concept.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
            System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
            MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\csharp.net-informations.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
            MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection);
            MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com");
            DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
            MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
            MyConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you can export a DGV to an Excel file using this methodology.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cnn ;
            string connectionString = null;
            string sql = null;

            connectionString = "data source=servername;initial catalog=databasename;user id=username;password=password;";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cnn.Open();
            sql = "SELECT * FROM Product";
            SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dscmd.Fill(ds);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp ;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0; 

            for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount  - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount  - 1; j++)
                {
                    DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[j, i];
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value;
                }
            }

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("csharp.net-informations.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);

            MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file c:\\csharp.net-informations.xls");
        }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }

    }
}
```